# How can I search in database in JSONB type?

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

The point is that I have a JSON column(foo_data) in the database table(foo).

I get errors when I apply any operation to JSONB.

For example, the JSON structure looks like this.

```
[
   {
      "KEY1":{
         "desc":"description 11",
         "value":11
      }
   },
   {
      "KEY2":{
         "desc":"description 22",
         "value":22
      }
   },
   {
      "KEY3":{
         "desc":"description 33",
         "value":33
      }
   }
]
```

As you can see, it is a list of key-value pairs.
I want to have all entities if the key occurs in the JSON structure.
I've tried various approaches, unfortunately without success so far.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM foo f WHERE JSONB_EXISTS(f.foo_data, '$[*] ? (@.key == :key)')", nativeQuery = true)
List<Foo> findFooByKey(@Param("key") String key);
```

This didn't work either.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM foo f WHERE JSONB_EXISTS(f.foo_data, '$[*] ? (@-> == :key)')", nativeQuery = true)
List<Foo> findFooByKey(@Param("key") String key);
```

I get an empty list.

Many thanks for tips and suggestions

Comment: what database are you using? is it postgresql?

Comment: Im using Postgres.